# FusionDrive + Encrypted CoreStorage Volume - Problems writing to volume

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, encryption, core-storage, fusion-drive

Has anyone had experience with encrypted (home made!) FusionDrive volumes and intermittent failure of writes to this disk?

I'm on a Late 2011 MBP 13" with (currently) 4 GB RAM, a 128 GB SSD and a 750 GB SATA disk.

When I'm trying to rsync data (from a TM backup) onto it, I get write failures.  I also could not successfully decrypt the volume when I tried.

I have stress tested the disks and they seem fine, and checked RAM, so other than a fault with the drive controller, which I doubt, I don't think it's a hardware problem.

Can anyone post success or similar failures with this kind of setup?

Comment: Is the TM volume local or over a network?  If its an AFP mounted destination, what OS is it hosted on?

Comment: It was remote via AFP (Netatalk on Ubuntu), but the source of the data surely shouldn't matter, should it?  I should add that I did exactly the same action once I'd reinstalled on a non-Fusion Drive set-up and it was all fine.

Comment: I have a factory 256GB SSD in my non-retina 2011 MBP 15" running OS X 10.8, backing up via TM to a remote AFP volume hosted originally on a OS X Server 10.6.8 box - and regularly had these bizarre hangs where network I/O would continue working (ssh or VNC sessions) but anything that required local storage I/O would stop responding.  I reformatted, hardware checks, etc etc etc.  The only solution was when I upgraded that server from SL to ML. Perfect since.

If you're not seeing any other r/w failures, just when using TM, try using a different TM destination: either same OS or local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having done this again it was a problem with the AFP mounted TM volume - why it caused write errors when copying FROM the volume I don't know but I've been running a fusion drive with the same SSD now - without rsyncing any data - for a few months and it's running really well.

Thanks all for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me when I have the SSD at the second bay, all was fixed when I put the SSD at the main bay in order to be shown as disk0

Comment: Unfortunately it was in the primary bay and was disk0...  Thanks for the follow up though.